# Finding limits at infinity in R

Tags: r

I am doing an R code to evaluate limits.
I am not sure if my code even works I just run it and then it doesn't give anything and R stop debugging code / gets stuck, nothing works right after not even print statements. fn is supposed to be any function and tol is the error tolrence, I want to stop the program when the consective terms difference is less than 1e-6. I have to restart R and I always get the message "R session is currently busy" when I try to close R studio

```
lim<-function(funx,tol=1e-6){
n<-1
while(TRUE){
  n<-n+1
  term<-funx
  next_term<-term+funx
  if(abs(term-next_term)<tol){
    break
  }
}
return(term)
}
n<-1
fn<-(1/5)**n
lim(fn)
```

Comment: why are you adding two consecutive terms of the function `funx`? It's really unclear as to what you really want...

Comment: I am trying to end program when the absolute value of two consecutive terms in the limit is smaller than the tol this is what i was instructed to do

Comment: @Jos are you trying to find the limit of the sequence `(1/5)^n` as n goes to infinity?

Comment: Yes this exactly

Comment: the while should keep running until its more than tolrence then it breaks unless thats all wrong

Comment: @Jos you did something wrong. Let me frame an answer for you...

Comment: Alright I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some mistakes in your program. For one, you always add the same number (`funx`) which will always be 0.20 and never smaller than the tolerance, so you get an endless loop.
If you want to call a function each time, you have to define this function and pass it to the `lim()` function. Otherwise, you just define `fn` as 0.20 and pass it as a double value to the function. It will never change.

If you want to find the limes of (1/5)^n, you can do it like that:

```
lim = function(f,x=1,tol=0.0001){
  next.diff=tol
  while(next.diff>=tol){
    next.diff = abs(f(x)-f(x+1))
    x = x + 1
  }
  return(list("Iterations"=x,"Limit"=f(x),"Next Value"=f(x+1)))
}

my.fun = function(x){(1/5)^x}

lim(my.fun,1,1e-6)
```

It wil lthen call the function for inceasing values of x and abort the loop as soon as the tolerance is reached. In this example:

```
> lim(my.fun,1,1e-6)
$Iterations
[1] 10

$Limit
[1] 1.024e-07

$`Next Value`
[1] 2.048e-08
```

So, at (1/5)^10 you already reach a value where the next iteration is closer than your tolerance. It's safe to say that it would converge to 0.

You can define any function of a value `x` and pass it to this lim function with a starting value for x and a tolerance level.

EDIT: For the limes of `sqrt(x+1)-sqrt(x)`, you would just have to define a new function of x (or of n, if you wish) and pass it to `lim()`:

```
> fun2 = function(x){sqrt(x+1)-sqrt(x)}
> lim(fun2,1,1e-6)
$Iterations
[1] 3969

$Limit
[1] 0.007936008

$`Next Value`
[1] 0.007935009
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear as to what you really want to find out here, but as far as I understood, you want to see where the **sequence** (not a function) (and of the type `a^n`) converges. Well, if that is the case, then you need to change your code to something like this:

```
lim<-function(a,tol=1e-6)
{
    n<-1
    repeat
    {
        term<-a^n;next_term<-a^(n+1)
        if(abs(term-next_term)<tol) break
        n<-n+1
    }
    return(term)
}
```

---

Ok so here's what I did:

1. I assumed that the sequence you input is of the form `a^n` where `a` is a constant term, and `n` increase on the set of natural numbers
2. I defined the value of `n` initially **inside** the loop (why? cause I want to iterate over all the possible values of `n`, one-by-one)
3. Then I defined the first term of the sequence (named as `term`). As assumed, it's `a^n` initially. So the next term (a.k.a. `next_term` in my code) should be `a^(n+1)`.
4. Now take their absolute difference. If it satisfies the condition, break out from the loop. Else, increase the value of `n` by 1 and let the loop run once again.
5. Then finally, return the value of the term. That's all...

I hope you will now be able to understand where you went wrong. Your approach was similar, but the code was of something else.

Remember, in this code, you don't need to enter the value of `n` separately while calling the function.

---

**Here's what it returned**:

```
> lim(1/5)
[1] 5.12e-07
> fn<-1/12
> lim(fn)
[1] 3.34898e-07
```

Comment: Thats the same value I got it when I did it without defining the code in a function.
can I throw any sequence at it? or does this only work for (1/5)^n

Comment: As mentioned in the beginning, you can throw any sequence at it, which has the form `a^n`... However, if you throw a diverging sequence at it (say `a`=2), you'll run into trouble, as it'll run infinitely many times...

Comment: However you can always set to terminate a program after a certain number of iterations... You can apply that here to terminate this program also, in case the sequence is a diverging one...try that out

Comment: How about a sequence in the form of sqrt(n+1)-sqrt(n) as telescoping series / sequence

Comment: By changing the `term` and `next_term` appropriately, you can do that too... Look out if you need `a` or not

Comment: If you need it for different mathematical functions, it might help to define the mathematical function you wish to find the limes of, separately. You can then pass it to the limes function and get the result, independent of your problem. I illustrate that in my answer.